# Retrieving Value from a WebElement using XPATH in Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

I have a WebElement which has a xpath as "//input[@type='date']" and it has a value as '11/08/2020'. I am using document.evaluate as below in javascript:

document.evaluate("//input[@type='date']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).

I am trying to retrieve the value (i.e. '11/08/2020'). I tried all the below mentioned options, but these options are not working

1. document.evaluate("//input[@type='date']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).value ->
   It shows 'undefined'
2. document.evaluate("//input[@type='date']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).stringValue ->
   It shows "Failed to read the 'stringValue' property from 'XPathResult': The result type is not a
   string."
3. document.evaluate("//input[@type='date']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).numberValue ->
   It shows "Failed to read the 'numberValue' property from 'XPathResult': The result type is not a
   number."

The 'ResultType' of the XpathResult is "4".

Could you please help me to know how I can retrieve the value from the WebElement.

Thanks...

Comment: This could be used in driver.executescript() for Javascript or you could driver.findelement((by.xpath,"//input[@type='date']" )).text in Python.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant html.